# Condicional if en python

Tags: python, excel, jupyter

solicito ayuda ya que no tengo idea de como resolver lo siguiente:
tengo un dataframe y tengo que hacer un calculo de **SI EL VALOR DE LOS DATOS DE UNA COLUMNA ES MAYOR A 0.416 QUE ME MULTIPLIQUE TRES COLUMNAS DE ESE DATAFRAME Y EL RESULTADO LO ALOJE EN UNA NUEVA COLUMNA SINO ES MAYOR QUE ME MULTIPLIQUE OTRAS TRES COLUMNAS**. Ese es el problema que tengo y no sé como solucionarlo, en excel la formulo así si(A1>0.416;((B2*86400)*C2);((D2*86400)*C2)) pero no sé como pasarlo a python.
Espero atento alguna ayuda o sugerencia.
Muchas gracias a todos por su atención.

Comment: Hola, Tenés algun código desarrollado?

Comment: Hola @AleBuo si, ya las anexo para especificar más el problema.

Comment: Detalladamente es así: If DF['medio']>0.416: producto=(DF['principal']*86400)*DF['secundaria'] else: producto=(DF['tercero']*86400)*DF['secundaria'] pero al aplicarlo me sale el error y ya no sé qué más hacer ayuda . Muchas gracias

Comment: Aunque ya has solucionado tu problema (genial), no está demás decir que para proveer más detalles debes pulsar en [edit] y agregarlo _en la pregunta_. En los comentarios es complicado leer código y aclaraciones. Además, podés darle formato a tu código agregando triples acentos graves (```) una línea arriba y una abajo de tal código. Aparte de eso, darle un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
A1=-1
B2=-1
C2=-1
D2=-1
COLUMNA_RESULTADO=-1

if A1>0.416:
    COLUMNA_NUEVA_1=(B2*86400)*C2
else:
    COLUMNA_RESULTADO=(D2*86400)*C2
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: muchas gracias, lo intenté de esa forma y me arroja el siguiente error (the truth value if a series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Detalladamente es así:                                    
 If DF['medio']>0.416:                 
         producto=(DF['principal']*86400)*DF['secundaria']        else:                                                                                                    
         producto=(DF['tercero']*86400)*DF['secundaria']               pero al aplicarlo me sale el error que te indique anteriormente y ya no sé qué más hacer ayuda . Muchas gracias

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad, por favor leer [answer]. Por otro lado, evita responder preguntas de tan baja o pésima calidad, porque terminarán cerradas y tu publicación se perderá.

Answer (score 1):

ya logré solucionar el problema, dejo la solución en la siguiente línea:

```py
df_prueba['quinta']=np.where((df_prueba['primero']>0.416),(df_prueba['segunda']*86400)*df_prueba['cuarta'], ((df_prueba['tercera']*86400)*df_prueba['cuarta'])
```

Por si en algún momento se llega a necesitar.
muchas gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Si la otra respuesta no responde la pregunta (es mas, no entiendo que responde) entonces porque esta marcada como aceptada?

Comment: Te diría que evites responder preguntas tan mal formuladas, pero en este caso se trata de una autorespuesta a una pregunta muy mal formulada. Te invito a leer [ask] y [answer]. La idea del sitio es generar contenido de calidad. Te invito a editar tu pregunta agregando un [mcve], de lo contrario terminará cerrada y esta respuesta se perderá. Saludos